# Silverstripe 4: Use submitted forms as a managed model

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to use the `SilverStripe\UserForms\Model\Submission\SubmittedForm` class as a managed model in my silverstripe 4 admin.

I am upgrading my site from ss3 to ss4 and am having an issue trying to use this class as a managed model. The 'submitted forms' tab appears but when I click to change to the tab I am getting the following error:

`error-log.ERROR: Uncaught Exception Error: "Call to a member function canCreate() on null" at /var/www/html/vendor/silverstripe/userforms/code/Model/Submission/SubmittedForm.php:133)`

Does anyone know why this is happening or anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: My guess is that the model wasn't designed with this use case in mind. The code expects it to have a `Parent()` record, which may not exist when you're viewing records in this context. You could raise an issue on the userforms GitHub repository and/or submit a patch to check for `Parent()` being truthy before being used =)

Comment: @RobbieAverill I decided to extend SubmittedForms and set canCreate to false as I would really like to keep the functionality how I used it in ss3. This has the desired outcome and now loads the managed model correctly however there is no data displaying in the table. I only have one form on my website and so I can hardcode the form ID or page ID in if required but do you know how I can access the form submissions saved in my database to display in my extension? I hope this makes sense